# How can I sum objects property of an array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, arrayobject

I have an array of objects, and i want to sum value of one of the property.Here is a picture which will show the structre of array.[image]

*Here is my code,that doesn't work*.

```
print_r($res);//this appear the structure of array,which i will show.   
$sum = 0;   
foreach($res as $key=>$value){ 
   if(isset($value->sent))   
        $sum += $value->sent;
   }   
echo $sum;
```

Comment: You need to loop around `$res->intervalStats`.

Comment: `->sent`? maybe you meant `->spent`

Comment: @ghost sorry its spent...bthway ...doesn't work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$sum = 0;
$result=$res->intervalStats;
foreach($result as $key=>$value){

if(isset($value->spent))   
    $sum += $value->spent;
}
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 13):

Make use of [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function like below

```
$sum = array_reduce($res->intervalStats, function($i, $obj)
{
    return $i += $obj->spent;
});
echo $sum;
```

**Sample Test**

```
 [akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php
 <?php

 $res = (object)array( "intervalStats" => array( (object)array("spent"=>1),(object)array("spent"=>5) ) );


 $sum = array_reduce($res->intervalStats, function($i, $obj)
 {
     return $i += $obj->spent;
 });

 // Input
 print_r($res);

 // Output
 echo $sum;
 ?>
```

**Output**

```
 [akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php
 stdClass Object
 (
     [intervalStats] => Array
         (
             [0] => stdClass Object
                 (
                     [spent] => 1
                 )

             [1] => stdClass Object
                 (
                     [spent] => 5
                 )

         )

 )

 6
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working on lates PHP versions (tested on 7.2)

`$sum = array_sum(array_column($res->intervalStats, 'spent'));`

Comment: This would work if the children are type of array .. here it is type of object.

Comment: @MahmoudAbdelsattar, it will still work if the properties are public, which seems to be so.